# Heading empty lines in html docs - WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, blank-line

I just launched my new website. Everything is working ok, HOWEVER, I just noticed the HTML docs (source code of the page) has 15 blank lines before "`<!doctype html>`". This is causing some issues for SEO and to generate automatic sitemaps.

I searched all over the web, and finally find the issue: the functions.php in my child theme (storefront). When I delete or rename the functions.php in the child theme, the HTML doc is shown normally without blank spaces. I tried deleting one by one the functions coded in the file, but the issue persists until I delete all functions together. Also, I disabled all plugins and nothing solves, only deleting the mentioned file. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

below is the current content of functions.php

````
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'my_remove_all_product_tabs', 98 );
function my_remove_all_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
  unset( $tabs['description'] );        // Remove the description tab
  unset( $tabs['reviews'] );       // Remove the reviews tab
  unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );    // Remove the additional information tab
  return $tabs;
}
?>

<?php // Este snippet regula el tiempo que se muestra el cart widget del WCPT
function wcpt_cart_js() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // your javscript code goes here
          jQuery(function($){
  $('body').on('wcpt_cart', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.wcpt-cart-widget ').fadeOut();
    }, 2000); // delay
  })
})
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wcpt_cart_js');
?>

<?php
/* quitar "Menu" del hamburger en moviles  */
add_filter( 'storefront_menu_toggle_text', 'storefront_menu_toggle_text' );
function storefront_menu_toggle_text( $text ) {
    $text = __( '' );
    return $text;
}
?>

<?php
/* quitar la barra menu inferior nativa storefront en moviles  
add_action( 'init', 'jk_remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar' );

function jk_remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar() {
  remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar', 999 );
}*/
?>

<?php
/**
 * Custom Filter for Gallery Image Captions
 *
 * Note: Avoid altering captioning, selector, and item tag.
 */
function mlc_gallery_image_caption($attachment_id, $captiontag, $selector, $itemtag) {

    $id = $attachment_id;

    // Grab the meta from the GIC plugin.
    $my_image_meta = galimgcaps_get_image_meta($id);

    /**
     * Here's where to customize the caption content.
     * 
     * This example uses the meta title, caption, and description. 
     * 
     * You can display any value from the $my_image_meta array. 
     * You can add your HTML too.
     */
    /*
    return "<{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='{$selector}-{$id}'>" .
           "Title: " . $my_image_meta['title'] . "<br>" .
            "Caption: " . $my_image_meta['caption'] . "<br>". 
            "Description: ". $my_image_meta['description'] .  
        "</{$captiontag}></{$itemtag}>";
    */
     return "<{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='{$selector}-{$id}'>" .
           $my_image_meta['caption'] . "<br>". 
        "</{$captiontag}></{$itemtag}>";

}
add_filter('galimgcaps_gallery_image_caption', 'mlc_gallery_image_caption', 10, 4);
?>

<?php
/**
 * Cambia el texto del boton "anadir al carrito"
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text','QL_customize_add_to_cart_button_woocommerce');
function QL_customize_add_to_cart_button_woocommerce(){
return __('Comprar', 'woocommerce');
}
?>

<?php
/**
 * Override theme default specification for product # per row
 */
function loop_columns() {
return 4; // n products per row
}
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
?>

<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'archive_custom_cart_button_text'); 

function archive_custom_cart_button_text()
{
    return __('Comprar', 'woocommerce');
}
?>

<?php
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'add_price_prefix', 99, 2 );
  
function add_price_prefix( $price, $product ){
    $price = '' . $price;
    return $price;

}
?>

<?php
if (wp_is_mobile()){
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title_mobile', 10 , 2 );
    /*mobile_storefront_page_header();*/
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 6 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 7 );
    
}
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
?>

<?php
function shorten_woo_product_title_mobile( $title, $id ) {
    if ( ! is_singular( array( 'product' ) ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' && strlen( $title ) > 20 ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, 42) . '..'; // change last number to the number of characters you want
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
?>

<?php
function mobile_storefront_page_header() {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            return;
        }

        ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            storefront_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
            ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        <?php
    }
?>

<?php
/**
 * Redirecciona el productos de los resultados en tabla a la pagina seo optimizada del producto agrupado
 */
add_action('template_redirect','custom_shop_page_redirect');
function custom_shop_page_redirect(){
global $post;
    if (class_exists('WooCommerce')){
        if(is_product()){
            $product = get_product( $post->ID );
            if( $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ){
            $slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;
            $nslug = str_replace("tienda/","",$slug);
            for ($x = 0; $x <= 20; $x++) {
            $nslug = rtrim($nslug,$x);}
            $nslug = rtrim($nslug,"-");
            wp_safe_redirect(home_url($nslug));
            exit();
            }
        }
    } 
    
    return;
} 
?>

<?php
/**
 * cambia el formato del precio de agrupados
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_price_html', 'grouped_price_range_delete', 'grouped_price_prefix', 10, 3, 2 );
function grouped_price_range_delete( $price, $product, $child_prices) {
$price = '';
return $price;
}
?>

<?php
/**
 * actualiza automaticamente el carrito al cambiar la cantidad
 */
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );
function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}```
````

Comment: It's all those white spaces that you create when you open/close the `<?php` tags. Remove all of them. You don't need to keep opening/closing them apart from within the `wcpt_cart_js` function. All the rest should be removed so you only have 1 `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry. Is now solved, i found the problem was the blank lines between each php open/close. Sorry for the useless post.
Regards!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).